# На go выдернуть из http ответа картинку в base64

Tags: golang

Суть задачи - есть POST-запрос на него в ответе приходит json в котором есть три картинки
Задача выдернуть только эти 3 картинки и сохранить себе на комп
вот кусок кода:

```go
body2, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
type images struct {
    Images []string `json:"images"`
}

data4 := images{}
err4 := json.Unmarshal(body2, &data4)
if err4 != nil {
    log.Println(err4.Error())
    return
}

fmt.Println(data4)
```

пример ответа:

```
{
  "images": [
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...",
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..."
  ]
}
```

вопрос правильно ли я делаю что бы выдернуть чисто base64 из images и как потом пройтись циклом по этим картинкам и сохранить по очереди их на комп?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо написать примерно такую функцию, которая будет принимать в качестве аргумента структуру `images` и, допустим, путь к директории, в которую вы хотите сохранять файлы:

```go
func saveImages(imgs images, path string) error {
    // итерируемся по массиву строк, с закодированными изображениями
    for i, img := range imgs.Images {
        // согласно data:URL (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL)
        // пытаемся разделить строку на описание типа и собственно закодированное изображение
        b64Parts := strings.Split(img, ",")

        // Если результирующий массив содержит 1 элемент, то вероятно, строка
        // не была data:URL-строкой, а была просто закодированным изображением
        // в таком случае берём единственный элемент массива
        // если же элементов 2, то вероятно это data:URL
        // в таком случае берём второй элемент массива
        // любые другие варианты говорят о невалидности
        var idx int
        if l := len(b64Parts); l == 1 {
            idx = 0
        } else if l == 2 {
            idx = 1
        } else {
            return errors.New("Некорректный base64")
        }

        // Пытаемся раскодировать изображение в массив byte
        data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64Parts[idx])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Пытаемся записать полученные данные в файл с индексом текущего элемента
        if err = ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v.png", path, i), data, 0777); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Теперь вы сможете вызывая `saveImages`, сохранять все картинки, полученные в вашем json:

```go
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// парсим json в структуру
var imgs images
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &imgs); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// получаем путь к директории исполняемого файла
dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// сохраняем картинки
if err := saveImages(imgs, dir); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло
Не до конца понял про путь к директории но картинки сохранились в папку с исполняемым файлом main.go

Comment: @Vint пометьте ответ, как правильный, пожалуйста, если он вам помог. Это даст понять другим участникам сообщества, что проблема решена.



Что касается пути, по которому сохраняются картинки, в том виде, в котором описано выше, берётся не директория файла `main.go` (это же не исполняемый файл), а директория уже скомпилированного запущенного файла или файла `debug`, если вы запустили программу в режиме отладки, просто на стадии разработки эти пути просто могут оказаться эквивалентными.

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ пометил как верный - немного изменил папку для сохранения используя метод join из пакета "path/filepath" - очень удобно)